# Xaml display map on half page , another half information in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create the following view. 
[my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTIk9.png)

I don't seem to achieve this, I tried different approaches but it did not work. Is this even possible in xamarin forms?
This is what I have: 
My view:

```
<StackLayout>
    <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap" 
                     MapType="Satellite" 
                     WidthRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenWidth}" 
                     HeightRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenHeight}" />

    <ListView x:Name="listviewname"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="20, 10">
                        <Label  Text="{Binding Information}"
                                 FontSize="15" 
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding More Information}"
                                 FontSize="15"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding MoreInformation}"
                                FontSize="15"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

But this it only shows my map. Some help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Try using a Grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Grid` to split the Page into 2 segments. something like should get you started:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <maps:Map Grid.Row="0" />
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="listviewname" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="20, 10">
                        <Label  Text="{Binding Information}" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding More Information}" FontSize="15"/>
                        <Label  Text="{Binding MoreInformation}" FontSize="15"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>            
</Grid>
```